# Remove "Undo Deleted" Popup in Ubuntu

Tags: files

Is there a way to remove the "Undo Deleted" popup in Files. I tried the answer provided for Nautilus however I could not find the directory/file to edit.

Ubuntu 19.10

GNOME 3.34.2

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I did in Ubuntu 20.04 to remove undo-deleted-popup.

However as pointed out by @vanadium in the comment, these below steps will remove any application popup, not only the delete dialog popup of nautilus

1. First in GNOME Tweaks tool check which is the current theme. Mine is Yaru

[image]

2. Check in `/usr/share/themes/`

Found Yaru (the same theme currently in use, as checked in GNOME Tweaks)

3. Now inside Yaru, had 2 folders named `gtk-3.0` and `gtk-3.20`

I opened Terminal from both of those folders one by one and ran

`sudo gedit gtk.css`

added the line

`.app-notification { padding: 0; margin: -80px 0 0 0; opacity: 0;}`

at the end

Saved file, closed, now refreshed theme in GNOME Tweaks (change to another theme, and again change back to your original theme in use).

Comment: You could warn that this will remove any application popup, not only the delete dialog of nautilus.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out @vanadium. Editing my ans.